# "Each" followed by "have"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Each' with plural or singular verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/each-with-plural-or-singular-verb)

Is the use of *have* after *each* grammatical here?

> Believe it or not, farther and further **each have** distinctly different meanings although people tend to use them interchangeably.

Comment: In this sentence, I believe _have_ refers to "farther and further", not "each", so the tense is correct. "Each" is an optional word in that helps accentuate the difference between the two similar words.

Comment: @J.R.- If I say: Mike and Jim each *has* a car. Is has ungrammatical here?

Comment: @Noah Yes, that would be incorrect grammer. See my answer for explanation.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if I can remember anyone _thanking_ @RegDwight for closing their question before. +1 on the comment, for cordiality.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct grammar. There are three forms of the word *each*:

1. A pronoun:

   > Each has distinctly different...
2. An adjective:

   > Each word has distinctly different...
3. An adverb:

   > The words each have distinctly different...

In this case, *each* is an adverb meaning "apart" or "apiece". The word could be replaced with the adverb *separately* and it would carry a nearly identical meaning:

> ... farther and further separately have distinctly different...

Therefore, the use of the verb form *have* is correct, since "farther and further" form the subject, which is plural.

Comment: What about the verb agreement of "*each of ...*"? For instance, is it a matter of personal choice, or is there a rule for the correct verb form in "Each of my three pens is/are green"?