# Which is preferable: "We are all..." or "We all are..."?

Tags: differences, word-order, syntactic-analysis, quantifiers

1. "We are all mad."
2. "We all are mad."

I think each of these conveys the same idea. Besides this, we can use "we are all" alone.
I hear the first one more frequently.

Does the second one sound worse to a native speaker? I wonder about this.

*Note: I'm not a native speaker.*

Comment: They do not mean precisely the same. See usage examples.

Comment: First one is definitely more prevalent, but I think the second has more elegance about it. Use that and you are likely to impress your listener!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but the first is more usual. *We are all* is much more frequent than *we all are* in both the Corpus of Contemporary American English and in the British National Corpus. There are, however, some contexts where *we all are* would be used. The answer to the question *Who is responsible?* might be *We all are*, and not *We are all*.

That apart, as a non-native speaker, you would be wise to stick to *We are all* when something else follows.

Answer (score 10):

*All* is a quantifier that allows the rule of Quantifier Float, which moves a quantifier from its normal position near its focus constituent to an adverbial position.

- *All the men left.* == Q-Float => *The men all left*.
- *All the men have been seen*. == Q-Float => *The men have all been seen.*
- *Each of the men left.* == Q-Float => *The men each left*.
- *Each man has left*. == Q-Float => *The men have each left.*

In the original sentence Q-Float can move *all* to either of two places:

- ***All** of us are mad*. (original, with *all* quantifying *us*)
- *We **all** are mad*.
- *We are **all** mad*.

All of these are grammatical, and mean the same thing.
These all are grammatical and mean the same thing.
These are all grammatical and mean the same thing.

Comment: When spoken, do we actually pronounce them identically? Exactly as the emphasis in style (boldface) above, the emphasis in pronunciation too stays with *all*, carrying with it the focus. Each therefore conveys a different "connotation" or at least a different point of emphasis. Correspondingly, the structures have their respective uses.

Comment: When spoken, _we are_ is almost always contracted to _we're_. Just like _I am_, which is very rare as two words in speech. Not contracting is so unusual that it draws attention to the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case in which it can be useful to talk about *denotation* and *connotation*.

Each of these ways of saying it is grammatically correct, and has the same fundamental content. The *denotation*, or in other words, the specific, explicit meaning is the same. The *denotation* can also be thought of as the *factual* content of the statement.

On the other hand, the *connotation* of each tends to be somewhat different. *Connotation* refers to the implied, suggested, or secondary meanings which are, in a sense, "hidden" below the surface of the words. In English, merely adjusting *word order* can significantly change the *connotation* of a sentence without changing its factual, *denotative* meaning. To put this more simply, yes, it can *sound* different to say it with a different word order, and thereby *suggest* or *imply* something different from what the other word order implies. But no, that does not mean that one sounds worse or wrong. They simply have different uses.

Now, in this case, just exactly *what* is implied by the two different word orders is something I won't go into at length, but I will say that in my opinion the first usually does have a more concrete, definitive, factual quality about it, whereas the second *can* be, and sometimes is, used for more eloquent, or sometimes even poetic, locutions.

Comment: A reasonable personal connotation. However, others will differ, since making fine distinctions between alternative and semantically identical syntactic variants is very idiosyncratic; most people don't make the same judgements.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree enthusiastically with that comment, Professor, which is why I tried to include a handful of qualifiers in my last paragraph. For the sake of others reading these comments, I'll add that context, intention, vocal intonations (when the words are spoken, of course), and other factors greatly influence the eventual conveyed meaning in each case (or at least what one hopes was conveyed). :)

Answer (score 1):

Though both are grammatically correct, but have different meanings. 'We are all mad,' means, 'We are totally mad.' And 'We all are mad,' means, 'All of us are mad.'

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: Nice answer I upvote it