# Subject phrase: 'Both of us' like sailing

Tags: subjects, determiners

I'm unsure whether or not 'both of us' and 'we both' are subject phrases. They are clearly in the subject position but in the first sentence 'both' is also a predeterminer, as far as I understand it, which would leave me with the object pronoun 'us' as the subject. Can someone help to unravel the grammar, please.

> **Both of us** like sailing.
>
> **We both** like sailing.

Comment: Both [of] these constructions are perfectly valid - or if you like, these constructions are both perfectly valid. It's a stylistic choice which format you use.

Comment: FumbleFingers, I'm more interested in the underlying grammar.

Comment: Relevant factors include the subject/object distinction *(**we/us, they/them,...**)* with personal pronouns, and the fact that for other "referents", the proposition ***of*** is usually optional. So *Both of the children are here* and *Both the children are here* are both fine. As is *Both children are here*, with no preposition *and* no "determiner" *(**the**)*, but note that *Both of children are here* (preposition included, but *no* determiner) is not valid. Sadly, I can't explain why that is so in terms of generalized syntactic principles, and I'm not sure if there might be any exceptions.

Comment: _Both of us_ is a noun phrase and it's the subject. _We_ is the subject in the other one; _both_ has been moved by [Quantifier-Float](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/128912/15299) from its position at the head of the noun phrase to an adverb position in the verb phrase. Since there's no auxiliary verb, it goes immediately before the main verb. But _we both_ is not a constituent; _we_ is the noun phrase and _both_ is part of the verb phrase.

Comment: Concerning "we both", I'd go along with JL. I'd add that "both" is a quantificational adjunct in clause structure, as is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary it preferentially follows rather than precedes it, as in "We had both liked the sailing". Note also the possibility of inserting an adjunct after the pronoun and before the quantificational adjunct. as in "We certainly both like sailing".