# Is ‘ask them to both be there’ or ‘they both will be there’ ever grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, adjectives, word-order, determiners

I am trying to articulate **how to position the determiner/predeterminer ‘both’ behind the nouns being modified**. Every rule that I came across on a cursory search involves some unspecified exception, so I have established this working guideline:

- if the nouns being modified are not within a complement clause and the sentence's first auxiliary verb (if any) is a single word, then insert ‘both’ right after this auxiliary verb;
- otherwise, insert ‘both’ immediately following the nouns being modified.

*Set A: it is always correct to put ‘both’ before its nouns* 
1a) **Both** x and y must be positive.
2a) Which of them is green? **Both** of them are (green).
3a) **Both** her sons visited the dentist.
4a) **Both** patients have gingivitis.
5a) I asked **both** of you to stop doing that!
6a) It's time for **both** my dogs to be fed.
7a) Let **both** the birds be free.
8a) The fact is that **both** of them are culpable.
9a) Make **both** Jack and Jill sprint.
10a) Invite **both** of us!

*Set B: putting ‘both’ behind its nouns, based on the above guideline* 
1b) x and y must **both** be positive.
2b) Which of them is green? They are **both** green.
3b) Her sons **both** visited the dentist.
4b) The patients **both** have gingivitis.
5b) I asked you **both** to stop doing that!
6b) It's time for my dogs **both** to be fed.
7b) Let the birds **both** be free.
8b) The fact is that they **both** are culpable.
9b) Make Jack and Jill **both** sprint.
10b) Invite us **both**!

*Set C: putting ‘both’ behind its nouns, flouting the above guideline* 
1c) x and y **both** must be positive. *
1d) x and y must be **both** positive.
2c) Which of them is green? They **both** are (green). *
5c) I asked you to **both** stop doing that!
6c) It's time for my dogs to **both** be fed. *
6d) It's time for my dogs to be **both** fed.
7c) Let the birds be **both** free.
8c) The fact is that they are **both** culpable. *

Is any sentence in *Set C*—in particular, the four asterisked sentences—grammatically sound or at least colloquially acceptable? Every dictionary and style/usage guide that I skimmed through finds at least one (or every) sentence in *Set C* to be grammatically problematic. (I'm pretty sure that *Set B* is fine.)

On a related note: without any italicisation or vocal emphasis, is *Set B* slightly more emphatic of its nouns' twoness/togetherness than *Set A* or do they have the exact same meaning?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148999/discussion-on-question-by-ryang-is-ask-them-to-both-be-there-or-they-both-wil); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

1. *Both* is just [the dual allomorph of *all*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155750/15299), and can go wherever *all* can go (give or take the occasional *of*).
2. *All* (and therefore *both*) can undergo [Quantifier-Float](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/128912/15299), moving from the noun phrase they bind to an adverbial position immediately after an auxiliary verb  in a clause. In a series of auxiliaries like (*is being*), after the first auxiliary verb is the preferred position, and more common, but before the first, or after the second are not uncommon and both are perfectly grammatical.
3. As to the revised question: Sorry, your guideline was wrong; but that's science for you. So, yes, both questions in the title are already grammatical, though I can't say about for *ever*. I.e, there's nothing wrong grammatically either with

> *Ask them to both be there,*
> or with
> *They both will be there.*

Comment: To be clear: are you saying that **Sets B and C are both totally grammatical**? // Your third paragraph's opening sentence is quite confusing: you refer to my "revised" Question and say that my working guideline "was" wrong: why the past tense, since (the revisions were primarily to alter and expand the example sentences and to focus my main query, and) the only change to my working guideline was the addition of that bit about complement clauses? In fact, how even *is* my working guideline wrong, since—if I have inferred correctly— **my working guideline produces no ungrammatical sentence**?

Comment: There are very few non-false-positives for 'Be both free' -'Be both free and' (vs 'both be free') in these [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=both+be+free%2Cbe+both+free%2C+be+both+free+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). I'd say it's heading for unidiomatic in strings like 'Let them be both free.'.

Comment: A lot of it seems to be about emphasis, rhythm, and prosody. If you are making a declaration like "Let them both be free", you get a nice dignified rhythm in that order, stressing the important words let/both/free, but "Let them be both free" less so. However, if the stress is primarily on "both" rather than the earlier part of the sentence, you can rearrange it to put both nearer the end rather than in the middle, the middle being generally less emphasised than the start or end.