# Send versus sends; and has versus have

Tags: grammaticality

I did a simple online English test and got two incorrect answers. Could someone please either explain the reason behind these two grammatical mistakes, or direct me in the direction of the grammar topic which I should read into? Note: I use British English.

Thank-you,

random7

[image: English test mistakes: Mr. Hawkins requests that someone ____ the data by fax immediately. Send versus sends. Each of the Olympic athletes ____ for months, even years. Has versus have.]

Comment: Regarding the correct choice of *send,* there's been a very recent answer on this site, please check. *Each* is singular, naturally, it's *has been,* not *have been.* Please visit [ell.se], also, go through previous posts on both these sites.

Comment: Suggested migrating to [ell.se]

Comment: Duplicate of not [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood) but [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/each-with-plural-or-singular-verb) utterly unrelated questions. Please ask one question at a time, and please [search the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=each%20singular%20plural) before asking.

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦: I don't know a lot about grammar, so I wouldn't know what to look for; hence why I wrote "or direct me in the direction of the grammar topic which I should read into". They are related through context (the online English test); hence why I posted them as the one question. I would suggest that you be a little bit nicer to new people.

Comment: I am flabbergasted you consider my comment not nice. I pointed you in the right direction on *both* grammar topics *and* showed you what you could have searched for without knowing anything about grammar, *and* accompanied every single suggestion with a *please*. Which cannot be said of your suggestion, by the way.

Comment: (And I am outright offended you chose to address me over the people who voted to close with a far less helpful comment, or with no comment at all.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt: sorry for the offence. I read your comment the wrong way (with a rude condescending tone). The cons of depression.
I also don't know how this website works, exactly; so I am a little confused about how to do things; what things mean; etc.

Comment: @everyone: well guys; you sure know how to scare away new people.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Nice as pie. Cherry – my favourite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subjunctive mode (or mood) requires the word send, because there is an "ought-ness" in Mr. Hawkins' request. When something is required of you (assuming you are the "someone" in your first question) or you are given a directive (or order, or command) by someone, the use of the subjunctive mode is appropriate. There seems to be a movement today toward eliminating that mode in both speaking and writing. Nevertheless, here are a few examples which may give you a "feel" for what the subjunctive is all about.

***Orders, Ought-ness, Commands, Things Required***

> - Ms. Hanley, the eleventh-grade English teacher, demanded that Ted, her student, *apologize* for his insensitive remark.
> - Jim's boss required of Jim, hired as a salaried employee, that he *put* in several hours of overtime each week.
> - Mr. Hazard told me, "I suggested to Sally that she *curb* her enthusiasm."

The subjunctive mode can also be used to express a wish, a desire, an imagined but impossible outcome, or anything in the realm of the impossible. Some examples:

> - If I *were* a rich man, I'd buy my parents a mansion in Florida, but that's just a pipe dream.
> - If I *were* you, I'd lease a new car instead of buying it.
> - Even though my new neighbor was a beautiful and single young woman, I knew that if I *were* to ask her on a date, she'd shut me down immediately.

***With "Each,"  "Every,"  and "Every Single One," for Example***

When one particular person in a group of people, for example, is being singled out and described as having done something, that one person is the focus, not the whole group.
The word *each* in your second sentence indicates one person; therefore, whatever his action has been is the focus, not the group's action.

> - The largest one of the statues *has* not been generating much interest in potential buyers.
> - Every single one of the team members *has* been raising money for the trip to the open competition in Seattle, which is 2000 miles away.
> - Only one of the many items up for bids *has* been available for immediate delivery since September 26; all the others cannot be delivered before the first of January.

In other words, a singular subject requires a single verb, even when the plural word is closer to the verb than the singular word.

Comment: HOWEVER: rhetorician's 'There seems to be a movement today toward eliminating that [ie subjunctive] mode in both speaking and writing.' and endorsement by say Quirk et al for the alternative choice of the indicative (here 'sends') in a mandative structure mean that labelling 'sends' incorrect here is incorrect. The test is essentially calling its preferred choice 'the [only] correct one'.

Comment: @rhetorician: thank-you for your very helpful response; it is much appreciated.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Point taken. That's why I used the word "appropriate" in my first paragraph. Personally, I'm comfortable with the subjunctive, but I wouldn't "correct" anyone who decided to use the indicative mode. Hey . . . , rules, schmools. Don

Comment: I don’t correct people who don’t use the subjunctive, either … but I do wince and cringe and die a little bit inside every time.

Comment: @Edwin: this use of the subjunctive is still very common in the U.S., but seems to be dying out in the U.K. To be correct in international English, use *"should send"* here.

Comment: @Peter I almost always would do. However, Quirk (ACGEL) licenses the indicative, which this test doesn't.

Comment: @Edwin: it's probably an American test; *sends* sounds wrong to the educated American ear (and I believe to a number of less well educated American ears, too), while *should send* sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Peter 'He looked out the window' sounds wrong to my ear, but I don't say it _is_ wrong.

Comment: @Edwin: I found the source. It's definitely a test written by Americans, even though it claims to be testing standard international English. So it's clearly wrong about that question (and, even worse, about the question that tests whether "the company" is plural or singular).