# Subject / verb agreement

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

None of the boys play / plays on the team.

Each of us want/ wants to have a piece of the pie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["None" as plural indefinite pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun)

Comment: and ['each' with plural or singular verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/each-with-plural-or-singular-verb).

Comment: Please actually ask what you are asking, don't leave us to guess from your examples.

Answer (score 1):

'Each' is singular.  'None' is not singular (so it gets lumped under 'plural' {or is it 'mass'?}.

None play.
Each wants.